# How do I create a multisignature wallet?

Tags: multisignature

I couldn't find a good way of doing it. https://wallet.gnosis.io appears to be broken. It was giving javascript errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason metamask didn't work but brave's crypto wallet extension did.